# Use asp.net button with a html form

Tags: asp.net, html, forms, http-post

I got a request to add this form to a asp.net control.

I want to use asp.net text box and button to submit the info to the form. (because I have special controls to match the look and feel).

this is the form:

```
<form name="ccoptin" id="signup" action="http://visitor.r20.constantcontact.com/d.jsp"
target="_blank" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="llr" value="yyyyyy">
<input type="hidden" name="m" value="xxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="oi">
<label>sign up for new services and promotions:</label>
<input type="text"name="ea" value="" class="text" /> 
<input type="submit" id="iframe" class="submit"
 name="go" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use asp.net Textbox control for html input control and you can put the same styling. e.g.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="ea" CssClass="text" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Button control for html submit button e.g.

```
 <asp:Button ID="iframe" CssClass="submit" runat="server" Text="submit" />
```

For your input type hidden, you can use asp.net `HiddenField` Control

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="llr" runat="server" Value="yyyyyy" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done . On browser side ASP.NET controls get converted in to HTML even if you use the asp.net button.

Drag and drop asp.net button from toolbox and put attribute id , cssclass , name , text . It will get converted in end to HTML as expected

```
<asp:Button id="iframe" cssclass="submit"
  Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. You have to consider these notes:

1. If you want to use ASP.NET controls, you should add `runat='server'` attribute to your `form` element. It's because ASP.NET controls (AKA server controls) while rendering check to see if they are get rendered in a server form (`VerifyRenderingInServerForm` method).
2. `<asp:Hidden` control is your replacement for `<input type='hidden'`
3. `<asp:TextBox` control is your replacement for `<input type='text'`
4. `<asp:Button` control is your replacement for `<input type='submit'`
5. All of your server controls should have `runat='server'` attribute

Comment: Welcome buddy. Don't mention that. :)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET only allows for one form with runat=server, and all of your server controls have to be within a form with runat=server.  Nesting forms isn't advisable.

See reference on form nesting:
https://web.archive.org/web/20170420110433/http://anderwald.info/internet/nesting-form-tags-in-xhtml/.

You'll need the form in a different document object - maybe host it in an iframe and conver the mini-form to an ASPX page that you load into the iframe ...

Comment: Not quite sure who dinged me, but read the guy's question - he wants to add the form to a control...  not possible.